# I want to stay in UK for a year as my partner has a job there

Tags: uk

My civil law partner will be working in UK for a year. She has a UK passport.
I have a New Zealand passport.
Will I be able to stay in UK beyond the 6 month limit?

Comment: Do you want to work there? You'd better post your question on http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Even if you don't want to work there, long term residence like this is best answered on the Expatriates site.

Answer (score 2):

There are no provisions in the rules for a visitor to stay for more than 6 months.

When your 6 months are up, you can try to "channel hop" to get another 6 months.  The current rules allow for this strategy, but now that exit controls are in place, it's risky.